# Square-well interaction between two particles in 3D

Tags: functions, physics

My question is about how one defines (as a function) a square-well type of interaction potential between two particles in 3D space. More precisely, as an analogy, one may have other forms of pair-wise interactions, such as $V(\mathbf r) = e^{-r/r_0}$ where $r$ is the distance between the two particles (point particles assumed), and here the potential $V$ is a quite simple exponential decay.

In contrast, how is the square well case generally defined? I've had two ideas but I don't know if either one is correct: (with $r$ the distance between the points and $a,\epsilon$ two given positive constants.)

- a) $$
  \begin{cases} 
        a & 0 < r < \epsilon \\
        0 & otherwise
     \end{cases}
  $$
- or b) $$
  \begin{cases} 
        a & 0 < r_{x,y,z} < \epsilon \\
        0 & otherwise
     \end{cases}
  $$

Do either of these definitions correctly represent a square-well type of interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conventionally, in the field of interaction potentials, the square well potential is taken to be spherically symmetric (the "square" refers to the shape of the potential curve vs $r$, not to the geometry in 3D). So your answer (a) is closest to the usual one, but not exactly right. Firstly, $a$ should be a *negative* constant, not a positive one, otherwise it would be a "hump" not a "well". Secondly, it is almost always understood that the square well has been added to an infinitely repulsive hard sphere potential which prevents atoms from overlapping each other. So, most people would understand a square well potential to be (adopting your notation)
$$
V(r) = \begin{cases} \infty & r < \sigma \\
-a & \sigma \leq r < \epsilon \\
0 & r \geq \epsilon \end{cases}
$$
with three parameters: $\sigma$ and $\epsilon$, the hard core diameter and well diameter respectively, both positive and with $\sigma<\epsilon$;  and $a>0$ (but with an explicit $-$ sign in the formula above), the well depth.

You can find out more about this model, and references to the literature, on the [SklogWiki](http://www.sklogwiki.org/SklogWiki/index.php/Square_well_model).